# Using Template Haskell, how can I splice the same type into multiple locations?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm defining instances of classes from [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) for the [OpenGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL) types, and to spare my typing muscles, I want to use Template Haskell to write a bunch of the instances for me.

I started out small by defining function to derive instances for `AdditiveGroup`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Data.VectorSpace.OpenGL.TH where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.AdditiveGroup
import Data.VectorSpace

import Language.Haskell.TH

deriveScalarAdditive ts = concat <$> forM (map conT ts) (\t -> [d| 
    instance AdditiveGroup $t where zeroV = 0; (^+^) = (+); negateV = negate
  |])
```

This works fine, but note that I'm only splicing `$t` once into the Oxford brackets. Now, the function to derive `VectorSpace` instances:

```
deriveScalarVectorSpace ts = concat <$> forM (map conT ts) (\t -> [d|    
    instance VectorSpace $t where type Scalar $t = $t; (*^) = (*)
  |])
```

But, this barfs:

```
Type indexes must match class instance head
Found `t_tt' but expected `t_ts'
In the associated type instance for `Scalar'
In the instance declaration for `VectorSpace $t'
In the Template Haskell quotation
  [d| instance VectorSpace $t where
          type instance Scalar $t = $t
          { *^ = (*) } |]
```

The difference between `t_ts` and `t_tt` in the error tells me that TH is creating a new, unique name every time I splice in `$t`, when of course the definition will only work if those types are the same.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want with Oxford brackets, or will I have to fall back to good old lexical scope and the `Language.Haskell.TH` combinators? I know this would probably be easier with the CPP, but I want to take this opportunity to learn some TH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have to use the `Language.Haskell.TH` combinators.  See the following tickets:

- [GHC 4230](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4230)
- [GHC 4135](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4135)

Doing so is very straightforward.  I would start with this (slightly formatted)

```
*Foo Language.Haskell.TH> runQ (deriveScalarAdditive [''Int] ) >>= print

[InstanceD [] (AppT (ConT Data.AdditiveGroup.AdditiveGroup) (ConT GHC.Types.Int))
  [ValD (VarP zeroV_12) (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL 0))) [],
   ValD (VarP ^+^_13) (NormalB (VarE GHC.Num.+)) [],
   ValD (VarP negateV_14) (NormalB (VarE GHC.Num.negate)) []]
]
```

from here, it's pretty simple to see how to construct instances using the combinators.  Also note that you can mix quoting with TH, a quoted expression `[| some code |] :: ExpQ`, which is often useful to create function bodies.